# Codeblocks project.exe has stopped working C

Tags: c, exe, codeblocks

Every time I build and run my project file, it crashes once I interact with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()  
{
    float complexnumber, a, b, r, j, theta;

    j = -1;  
    complexnumber = a+b*j;

    printf ("Please enter intput A and B in the form of a+bj\n");

    printf ("Input A:");  
    scanf ("%f" , a);

    printf ("Input B:");  
    scanf ("%f" , b);

    theta = atan (a/b);  
    printf ("Theta=\n" , theta);

    r = sqrt (pow(a, 2) + pow(b , 2));   
    printf ("R=\n" , r);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: It's a shame `scanf` can't ensure proper types.

Comment: Why do you have the line `complexnumber = a + b * j` when `a` and `b` are both uninitialized? When you say "when I interact with it", which point do you mean specifically? What values are you inputting?

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf ("%f" , a);
```

`scanf` needs a pointer to the variable it shall fill, so that must be

```
scanf ("%f" , &a);
```

and similarly for `b`.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to include the header file `<math.h>`.

Your `printf()` statement

```
printf ("Theta=\n" , theta);
```

looks incorrect,

it should be,

```
printf ("Theta=%f\n" , theta);
```

Similarly,

```
printf ("R=%f\n" , r);
```

Your `scanf()` statement is also wrong, it should be

```
scanf("%f",&a);
```

The line `complexnumber = a+b*j;` will assign garbage value to `complexnumber` as both `a` and `b` are uninitialized.